# How to create a shorter webhook API URL for Keen.io?

Tags: webhooks, keen-io, postmark

I'm trying to send the delivered email webhook from Postmark to Keen.  When I paste the webhook URL with the API key in the Postmark admin screen form and click check it works fine.  (201 status code.)  But then I save it and the check no longer works - it says not authorized.

It turns out the URL is too long - Postmark restricts it to 255 char.  So when I save it the end of the key gets cut off.

The 'write' key on Keen is huge.  (And I definitely don't want to use the master key!)  Any solutions to create a shorter API key on Keen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a custom `Access Key` it will be shorter than the default read/write keys that exist in your account.

Some helpful docs here: https://keen.io/docs/access/access-keys/

You're absolutely correct, the Master Key would also be shorter, but there are security risks to weigh if you choose to use it. (Note: using master key as your go-to key is not recommended!!! :))